# Fluentd out_forward

Tags: plugins, tcp, fluentd

Follwing TCP 3WAY handshake client disconnects. I am just trying to send raw tcp packets, no TLS. The Config file is as follows:

```
        <source>
        @type syslog
        @label @data
        port 5140
      bind 0.0.0.0
        tag system
       <parse>
        message_format rfc5424
        </parse>
    </source>


<label @data>
<match **>
   @type forward

    <server> ##destination servers
        name MXX
    host 192.1.X.XX
    port 24224
    </server>

</match>
</label>
```

I am using the same source directive for in_syslog to match mongo and out_forward plugins. I am confused as to why the client disconnects as shown in the screenshot.
[Wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sjmk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Stupidity got the best of me...I was not pushing data from an external server. In short the config file is fine